# Correct .NET Core SDK to build netstandard20 library

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard-2.0, .net-core-sdk

I have a few libraries with target framework `netstandard20`. These libraries are consumed by a few `.net framework 4.6.1` libraries.

The IT department uninstalled the **.NET Core 2.0** from the build server because of some security vulnerability. All the libraries that use `netstandard20` are now failing with the following error:

**C:\bamboo6104...>nuget restore
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.11.2.50704' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
C:\bamboo6104\xml-data\build-dir\BAM-CUS-JOB1...\netstandard\xxx.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.**

The Build Server already has **Visual Studio 2019**. What version of SDK need to be installed for the build to pass? I have the following SDKs on my laptop:

[image]

Will installing **2.1.526** version resolve the build issue?

I can't upgrade the libraries to .NET 5 or 6 due to we have numerous libraries with the same problem and upgrade is not a priority.

Comment: They are targeting the version your IT department uninstalled.  You will need to reinstall it, or else upgrade your app to a newer version without the vulnerabilities.

Comment: Which version of **.NET Core 2** does not have vulnerability, so it can be reinstalled?

Comment: If 2.1.526 is installed on your build server, you can target it specifically in `global.json`, but this might require changes to your application code.

Comment: Is ```global.json``` used per project? I have many projects with different targets.